# How Private is the Code your write using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, ide, deno

Since my [previous attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5MAP.png), to ask this question was `closed` for not being "focused" enough. Please focus your attention on only this:

**How private is the code you write in Visual Studio code? Specifically, does any outside resource see the code you've written in Visual Studio code?**

For example, Visual Studio has a lot of features that aid you in writing code. Are all those features locally self-sufficient, or does Visual Studio Code upload your code to cloud resources in order to facilitate some of those features?

If Visual Studio Code uploads your code to do processing, I'd consider that a violation of my privacy. I do not use Visual Studio code yet and this is a legitimate concern of mine before starting to use it.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_what-online-services-does-vs-code-use - Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @JohnPavek Yes. That link took me to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/telemetry#_managing-online-services). Well, it looks like a lot is on by default, but at least you can turn it off.

Comment: I found this [article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/04/17/vscodium.aspx). Apparently, the open source community has already taken measures to address my vary concerns. They provide [vscodium](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium) which is VS Code, but with community-diven defaults. Here [why](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium#why-does-this-exist) it exists.